# Difference between User.register and User.create in mongodb, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman, user-registration

I have been observing both of these codes below, I didn't get what's the difference. Can anyone explain please.

`User.register(new User({ username: req.body.username})......`

and

`User.create(new User({ username: req.body.username}).....`

**User** is the model I have created in mongodb (it stores as in **users** collection), and I'm going to add new field **username**.
In both the cases, been able to add successfully.

Comment: Are you referring to `mongoose`? It would be more helpful if you also mention the library you are referring to.

Comment: Yes @TheeSritabtim, I'm using mongoose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using `passport-local-mongoose` where [`register()`](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose/blob/master/index.js#L222) is a convenient helper for creating and setting password for a new user.

`User.register()` is from `passport-local-mongoose` which will insert a new user, if not already exists, using `user.save()`

`User.create()` is from `mongoose` which internally calls `user.save()` to insert a user document as well.